# replaceAllメソッドで大文字と小文字を区別せずに判定する方法

Tags: java

Javaの`replaceAll`メソッドについて質問です。
以下のコードで`replaceAll`を使い、大文字のAと小文字のaを両方含めBに変換したいのですが、
以下のコードだと大文字のAだけが`replaceAll`に反応してしまい、小文字のaが反応しません。
`replaceAll`で大文字小文字区別せずに検出するには、どのようなコードを書けばいいでしょうか？
`equals`と同じように`replaceAll.IgnoreCase`なども試してみましたが、`cannnot find symbol`とエラーが出てきてしまいます。

---

**現状のコード：**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        String str = "AaBbCc";
        String afterStr = str.replaceAll("A","B"); //ここで本来なら大文字小文字区別せずに出力する
        System.out.println(afterStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
    String afterStr = str.replaceAll("(?i)a","B");
```

[CASE_INSENSITIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE)

> `public static final int CASE_INSENSITIVE`
>
> Enables case-insensitive matching.
>
> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched. Unicode-aware case-insensitive matching can be enabled by specifying the UNICODE_CASE flag in conjunction with this flag.
>
> **Case-insensitive matching can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?i)**.

Answer (score 0):

大文字のAと小文字のaを両方含めBに変換したいのであれば、

```java
String afterStr = str.replaceAll("A","B");
```

を

```java
String afterStr = str.replaceAll("[Aa]","B");
```

に変えればAとaがBに置換できます。